# Newcommand with spaces after each letter

Tags: letterspacing

How can I make a command `\headline{COURSE PROJECT}` that would result in

```
\textbf{C\,O\,U\,R\,S\,E\;P\,R\,O\,J\,E\,C\,T}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package soul can be of help:

```
\textbf{\so{CURSE PROJECT}}
```

Of corse, in preamble you need to put:

```
\usepackage{soul}
```

Answer (score 6):

Besides using the `soul` package you can use [microtype's](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) `\textls`-command for this if you use pdfTeX 1.40 or LuaTeX 0.62.

From page 23 of the microtype (v2.5a) manual:

> > `\textls [< amount >] {< general text >}`
>
> While the tracking feature, described in section 5.3, will apply to sets of fonts, you may also want to letterspace shorter pieces of text, regardless of the font in which they are typeset. For such ad-hoc letterspacing, microtype introduces two commands that can be used (independently of whether the tracking option is enabled) in the same way as LaTeX’s text commands: `\textls` – which also works in math mode – expects the text in the mandatory argument, while `\lsstyle` will switch on letterspacing for all subsequent fonts until the end of the current group.

I strongly recommend reading the whole section on letterspacing.

So finally:

```
\newcommand{\headline}[1]{\textls{#1}}
[...]
\begin{document}
\headline{COURSE PROJECT}
[...]
```